# Virginal Defloration and Nidah

Tags: halacha, niddah

To the best of my knowledge there is a principle that if a woman knows with reasonable certainty ( or even reasonable suspicion ) that an emission of blood is from a wound and not from the uterus then she is not rendered niddah.  This comes up often for instance in the case of gynaecological exams that can cause non-uterine bleeding.

If this is the case, then why would a woman be rendered niddah ( or safeq zavah or whatever you want to call it ) after defloration considering that we know with certainty that the blood is from the broken hymen.

Comment: It's Rabbinic .

Comment: @DoubleAA Could you expand on that a bit, be a bit more specific?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes, in this particular instance, it is a rabbinic decree, since she experiences certain sensations that also might mask the sensation of a flow, just as the blood seen might mask the Dam Niddah, as might the seminal emission (if no blood is visible).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The source of this exception from dam makkah is a mishna on [Niddah 64b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=nidah&daf=64b), and the gemara on [Niddah 65b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=nidah&daf=65b).

There's a big machloket in the Rishonim about the reason why we have this exception to the general rule that blood from a wound is not niddah blood. I don't know them all of the top of my head, and I recommend [The Laws and Concepts of Niddah by Rabbi Zvi Sobolofsky](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592643256) for a full treatment.

The reason we poskin by is that it's a rabbinic decree, enacted because she might emit niddah blood at the same time, and not be aware of it.

Comment: In English Niddah 64b http://halakhah.com/niddah/niddah_64.html#64b and Niddah 65b http://halakhah.com/niddah/niddah_65.html#65b